# Is there any way to update mat-table data source when some one add new record?

Tags: angular, angular-material, refresh, angular-material-table

I'm using angular material mat-table to view records from database but when someone add new record to the database it doesn't appear in the table so I need to reload the page to get updated.

Is there any way to make data source updated without reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

To update the table you can call `renderRows()` on Angular Material Table.

import `ViewChild` and `MatTable`:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTable} from '@angular/material';
```

Then you can get a reference to the table using the ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
```

Then when you modify the table in any way you will need to call the renderRows() method.

```
updateTable(row: any): void {
  /* update logic here */
  this.table.renderRows();
}
```

Check this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxrahf